# Download OpenStreetMap relation data as shapefiles

Tags: openstreetmap

I've identified this [OpenStreetMap link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/7673622) which contains OSM's relationship id. I understand that there is download the data as `xml` with this [link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/7673622), and it returns the `ref` attributes.

How do I proceed to obtain the coordinates of these `ref` as a shapefile?

Comment: The XML file doesn't seem to have any spatial data so difficult to see how you could encode the information as a shapefile

Comment: hi @nmtoken, I know that, but the id refers to something, and what I am asking is what it is referring to, or in other words; how to get to the shapefile based on those ```ref```

Comment: You will probably have to run an overpass query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append "full" at the end of the link and the XML result contain coordinate tags
for instance: `https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/7673622/full`